# C# - ASPX - Checkbox needs to be checked only if certain text is in the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a small piece of code that allows me the have a checkbox checked or not checked depending on the text value of the Checkbox.

For example: If the text value of the checkbox is "Yes" it needs to be checked. If it's not "Yes" it shouldn't be checked.

This is what I have:

ASPX-page:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract Check" SortExpression="Contract_Check" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_contract_check" Checked='<%# contractCheck(Container.DataItem) %>' Text='<%# Bind("Contract_Check") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind File:

```
protected String contractCheck(CheckBox obj)
    {
        if (obj.Text == "Prior Transition")
            return "True";
        else
            return "False";}
```

However this is not working. Do you guys have any idea how I can get this too work?
Thanks

Kevin

Comment: What is the type/value of obj when you step into the contractCheck method?  If you force a return value of true is the check box checked?

Comment: The textvalue of the checkbox has 2 possible values:
For example:
If the textvalue is "a" it should be checked
if the textvalue is "b" it shouldn't be checked.
Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options in my mind:

**1 - Inline logic: Updating the aspx  (no function required)**

You should be able to just put the logic inline, directly into the markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract Check" SortExpression="Contract_Check" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
        <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_contract_check" Checked='<%# Eval("Text").ToString() == "Prior Transition" %>' Text='<%# Bind("Contract_Check") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

(the amended part is `Checked='<%# Eval("Text").ToString() == "Prior Transition" %>'`)

**OR**

Option 2 - Separate Logic: Update the function

If you'd prefer to keep the logic separate, then there are a couple of changes to make.  You are currently passing in the data item, not the `Checkbox` (which is what your function is expecting).  The second issue is that you need to return a `bool` from your logic function, not a `string`.  You need to make two changes in this instance:

1 - Pass in the text to be checked to the function in the aspx

`<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_contract_check" Checked='<%# contractCheck(Eval("Text").ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Bind("Contract_Check") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" />`

2 - Amend the function to check the text, and return a `bool`

```
protected bool contractCheck(string text)
{
    return text == "Prior Transition";
}
```

Basically, the `Checked` attribute requires a `bool` to work, and you're giving it a String.

Comment: I might be wrong on this one, but in the ASPX page it never calls the contractCheck function. Is it me or do I look over it? :)

Comment: @KevinParijs; sorry, I haven't been clear.  I've given you 2 options - one involves changing the aspx so that you don't need the function.  The other involves changing the function instead - I'll update the answer to be more explicit :)

Comment: @KevinParijs - great! If it answered your question for you, it'd be great to mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom CheckBox control (inherit from CheckBox), then put the code-behind logic in there to check the box if necessary when the text is set?

Here's a link that may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28783/Your-First-ASP-NET-Custom-Control

Comment: This might be working good, but I find it pointless if I have to create a custom control only for 1 thing in my aspx page.
If I had to use that control multiple times in the webpage then I would consider this. Anyway thanks for the link ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your contractCheck method needs the object that can be evaluated

Like this

```
protected String contractCheck(Object obj)
{
        if (DataBinder.Eval(obj, "Name of the field").ToString() == "Prior Transition")
            return "True";
        else
            return "False";}
```

Comment: with "Name of the field" do you mean the ID of the Checkbox?